# How to check the dojo topic event is subscribed or unsubscribed

Tags: dojo

```
   someMethod : function() {  
        if ( !this._evt ) {
            this._evt = topic.subscribe("some-evt", lang.hitch(this, "_someOtherMethod"));
        } else {
            this._evt.remove();
            //Here this just remove the listener but the object this._evt is not null 
        }
    },
```

Here i just want to know how can we came to know that this class already subscribed to the **'some-evt'**.

I don't want to set `this._evt = null;` to null after `this._evt.remove();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but the `dojo/topic` implementations typically do not provide a list of `topics` that have been `published`/`subscribed` to, and neither who `published`/`subscribed` to that topic. Dojo’s implementation conforms to this standard that there is no built-in mechanism to acquire a list of topics. Note that `dojo/topic` only have 2 functions, `publish` and `subscribe`.

You should implement your own idea, something like a `mixin` with a function to subscribe to a `topic` and keep a track of topic names registered, this is just an idea

The **_TopicMixin.js**

```
define(["dojo/topic"], function(topic){

    return {
        topicsIndex: {},

        mySubscribe: function(topicName, listener){
            this.topicsIndex[topicName] = topic.subscribe(topicName, listener);
        }

        myUnsubscribe: function(topicName){
            if(this.topicsIndex[topicName]){
                this.topicsIndex[topicName].remove();
                delete this.topicsIndex[topicName];
            }
        }

        amISubscribed: function(topicName){
            return this.topicsIndex[topicName];
        }
    };
});
```

How you can use it

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare","myApp/_TopicMixin"], function(declare, _TopicMixin){

    return declare([_TopicMixin], {

        someMethod : function(){
            if ( !this.amISubscribed("some-evt") ) {
                this.mySubscribe("some-evt", lang.hitch(this, "_someOtherMethod"));
            } else {
                this.myUnsubscribe();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps